# Register method to run at tearDown in python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have two scenario for this

00 mock some method and register the method call for unmock right away

01 insert some fixture rows to test database and register the method call to clean them up right away

I can call these `clean up method` at tearDown() but that will appear in hundreds of my test classes.

Is there any way to register method that will be executed when tearDown() called?

p.s.

My search not helpful with google [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20unittest%20register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown&oq=python%20unittest%20register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown&aqs=chrome..69i57.886j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and on our stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20unittest%20register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown&mixed=1)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup?

Comment: That's perfect. Can you add your answer to get accepted please? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Use `addCleanup()` [try it](https://repl.it/@NamG1/register-method-to-run-at-teardown-in-python-unittest)

```
import unittest


def my_code(my_var):
  print(f'in my_code with my_var={my_var}')


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

  def test(self):
      # your test goes here
      self.addCleanup(my_code, my_var='some value')  # register this clean up when test ended
```

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for the hint.