# Register method to run at tearDown in python unittest using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Similar question but for **unittest** is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63861092/248616)

I know that pytest is compatible with unittest.

I wonder what is the **built-in** in **pytest** a.k.a. pure-pytest way to register on-exitting event of a test run?

p.s.

My search [on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown%20in%20python%20unittest%20using%20pytest%3F&oq=Register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown%20in%20python%20unittest%20using%20pytest%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.411j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [on our stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Register%20method%20to%20run%20at%20tearDown%20in%20python%20unittest%20using%20pytest%3F&mixed=1) not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a session-scoped [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) that yields when it starts up and then performs teardown operations after the yield. A toy demo:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope = 'session')
def db():
    yield 'DbConnection()'
    # Occurs after all tests run.
    print('TEARING DOWN')

def test_foo(db):
    print(db, id(db))

def test_bar(db):
    print(db, id(db))
```

Output:

```
pytest-teardown.py DbConnection() 4489248432
.DbConnection() 4489248432
.TEARING DOWN
```